# Volt Framework Task returns string

Tags: voltrb

I am currently working on a sports app.
Users should be able to create new teams and add users to the teams.
When a user creates the team, he/she should be able to search for users to add to the team, however the search should only return users that are not yet part of the team.
I created a task for it, here is the method

```
def search_users_for_team(team_id, search_item)
    available_users = Array.new 
    temp_users = store._users.where(name: { '$regex' => /.*#{search_item}.*/, '$options' => 'i' }).all
    team_users = store._teams.where(id: team_id).first._members
    team_users_ids = []
    team_users.each{ |user|
        team_users_ids << user.id
    }

    temp_users.each{ |user|
        if !team_users_ids.include?(user.id)
            available_users << user
        end         
    }
    available_users

end
```

However i always get a string back from the function.

Did i miss something about tasks in volt.

I use volt 0.9.4.

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: What string do you get back?  You call methods on tasks as class methods, then they return a promise:

```SomeTask.search_users_for_team(...).then do |val|
  puts val
end```

Comment: Seeing how you called the Task and specifically what string was returned would be useful here.

Comment: i get a string which is the representation of the values

Comment: Volt::ArrayModel[#<User id: "1aba...asdas"> ]
Basically what i get when i use volt console

Comment: Can you try Volt::ArrayModel.new instead of Array.new?

Comment: I will. Until now, i was using to_h on the result to make it work